# "define this label in the resource bundle" bug sonarqube

Tags: html, sonarqube

I have several "define this label in the resource bundle" bug in my recent sonarqube scan

Here is a sample of a line of my code that gets this bug:

```
<p id="weekly" onclick="weeklyFilter()">Weekly</p>
```

Sonarqube suggests to transform it this way:

```
<label for="username"><fmt:message key="login.label.username" />:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
```

Any suggestions on how to implement this for `<p>`

Thank you

Comment: I think it wants you to replace the hardcoded string "Weekly" by a translation marker.